# Surface Edges Appear Beveled

Tags: modeling, nurbs-surface

I extruded a curve and the result has the right geometry but the shadows appear wrongly on the flat surface. How/what do I have to adjust to correct it? I already checked for duplicate vertices.

[image]

[image]

Comment: hello it's a bit hard to understand what's happening, maybe share the curve: https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/

Comment: [<img src="https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/embedImage.png?bid=7g3JJzAo" />](https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/b/7g3JJzAo/)

Answer (score 1):

If you're talking about this shape, increase its V resolution:

[image]

Comment: The answer by moonboots is correct, it's depending on the curve's resolution. I opened the file and found that actually both _U_ and _V_ resolutions have to be cranked up high to look like something you can achieve with a mesh and _Auto Smooth_. Actually I had to go beyond 200 as _V_ resolution before it began to look anything like a slightly beveled edge. On _U_ resolution I had to set it manually to over 500 (because the slider stops at 64). So although this works, for really sharp or just slightly beveled edges I'll post an optional answer.

Answer (score 1):

Since the *Auto Smooth* option is not available for curves at the moment, you can do the following to get sharp(er) edges with a smoothed surface:

1. Use the *EdgeSplit Modifier* to get sharp, unbeveled edges. The default settings should be fine, but you can set the *Edge Angle* to something higher close to 90°, since you only want to bevel the border edges.
2. For beveled edges, use the *Bevel Modifier*, set *Width Type > Percent* (that seemed to be the only width type where you don't need a high number of segments, but might depend on the curve's *U/V resolution*). Set values for *Percent* and *Segments* according to your liking.